# tab-expansion and "./" bash shell

Tags: bash, scripting, environment, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu

Maybe someone here would be able to help me out. Have installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (kubuntu) on two machines. The `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` files are identical as the file structures on each machine is the same.

**On machine 1**: I run bash scripts within a terminal window with the simple: `./scriptname.sh`

**On machine 2**: I cannot do this and must use: `sh scriptname.sh`
Nor can I use `./` and tab-complete the script filename.

All executable bits are set correctly, all files and folders have the correct permissions. In the header of the scripts the shebang is set correctly.

Any ideas why this would be occurring?

If I try to execute the script with `./file_motion_grab.sh`:

```
bash: ./file_motion_grab.sh: Permission denied
```

When I try `ls -l`, I get:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 adelie adelie 351 Nov 4 20:32 file_motion_grab.sh
```

Output of `getfacl` is:

```
# file: file_motion_grab.sh
# owner: adelie
# group: adelie
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx
```

More general - any new script on the second machine must be invoked with: sh scriptname.sh Something probably wrong in the .bash files. But not sure where to look.

Comment: Wait, you mean `./scriptname` (without a space after the / ?)

Comment: There is no `./` command in bash.  You mean, `./scriptname`, which is just the pathname to the script, right?  And are you sure the script is both readable *and* executable?

Comment: Correct ./scriptname.sh doesn't work on machine 2, but works fine on machine 1.

Comment: All permissions are correct, it is set correctly as readable and executable.

Comment: So what exactly happens when you type "./scriptname.sh" and press the enter key?

Comment: bash: ./file_motion_grab.sh: Permission denied

Comment: And what do you see if you type `ls -l`?

Comment: but if I run: sh file_motion_grab.sh  - no problem .

Comment: -rwxrwxrwx 1 adelie adelie     351 Nov  4 20:32 file_motion_grab.sh

Comment: This isn't really a programming question.  Perhaps it should be on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Sure - can ask it over there. Its really confusing me - not something I have run into in 10 years of using linux.

Comment: How about `getfacl file_motion_grab.sh`? By the way, it would generally be better to edit your question to include these answers, than post in the comments; more people will be able to see it if it's in the question. (edited to correct command `getfacl` instead of `getfactl` which was a typo).

Comment: # file: file_motion_grab.sh
# owner: adelie
# group: adelie
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx

Comment: I didn't mean put the entire question and answer thread into the question. Just the commands you ran and the exact output. Also, in the question, you can format things as a code block by indenting with 4 spaces. This can allow you to represent multi-line input and output exactly, preserving space.

Comment: also asked on [unix&linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/53858/4667)
 and [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/q/212005/10127)

Comment: Thanks Brian - new to needing to use this.

Comment: I've reformatted your question for you; if you've asked this elsewhere, you may want to do the same for the other questions. It makes it easier to read, and for other people to solve it, if all of the relevant information is in one place, and well formatted; that's why there's the difference between question/answers and comment threads.

Comment: Oh, I encounter this case one time when try Ubuntu 12.10 then back top Fedora in day. It's unable to run sh file. I think it maybe bug of ubuntu :D

Comment: One more question, as a shot in the dark. What are the permissions on the directory? `ls -al` instead of `ls -l`.

Comment: All the permission from top to bottom are correct. So weird that it works on one machine, but not the other.

Comment: Another shot in the dark: try `head -n 2 file_motion_grab.sh | xxd` and paste the results; I want to see if there are any extraneous characters (possibly invisible) that might cause it not to recognize the shebang.

Comment: 0000000: 2321 2f62 696e 2f62 6173 680a 0a         #!/bin/bash..

Comment: I tried set list in vi - nothing there I could see

Comment: OK. How about checking the permissions on `/bin/bash`; if it isn't working on any shell script, that's what I'd try next.

Comment: Nope - bash permissions correct and identical on both machines.

Comment: You say that `sh file_motion_grab.sh` works, but the shebang line is `#!/bin/bash`. Does `/bin/bash file_motion_grab.sh` work?

Comment: yes /bin/bash file_motion_grab.sh works

Comment: I've added a couple more things to try in my answer (other shells on the shebang line, check `binfmt_misc`, try another account, try rebooting). Take a look and try those if you can.

Comment: Hi Brian - rebooting gave no joy, running it as "sudo ./file_motion_grab.sh" doesn't work, nor are my python scripts working. Its just coming up permissions denied. Time to strip the bash env files down to zero and start rebuilding from there I think. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Wow, all that and still not working. So, Python scripts don't work either? Did you take a look at the `binfmt_misc`? You can also try taking a look at the output of `env` on both machines, and see if there's anything different. It might be worth trying `diff -u $<(env) $<(ssh othermachine env)` (assuming you have `ssh` set up so you can log in with no password, by using an SSH agent) to see the differences. Also, try checking out the differences between `ldconfig -p` on both machines, to see if there are any shared library difference that might affect you.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend trying `ls -al` to check the permissions on the file and the directory. Also, try `getfacl file.sh`, because sometimes there are ACL permissions that override the normal Unix permission bits.

Then I would try `head -n 1 file.sh | xxd`, to look at the first line, and make sure the shebang is there properly as the first two characters of the file. Sometimes, hidden characters, like a Unicode BOM, can cause it not to be interpreted properly.

Then I would check the permissions on the shell itself. `ls -l /bin/bash` and `getfacl /bin/bash`. I would also check to see if this happens with other interpreters; can you use `#!/bin/sh` for a script? `#!/bin/python` (or Perl, or Ruby, or something of the sort)? Distinguishing whether this happens only for `/bin/bash` or for other shells would be helpful.

Also, take a look at `ls /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc` to see if you have any binary formats configured that might interfere with normal interpretation of a shell script.

Try testing from another account as well (if you can). Is the problem unique to your account? I would also try rebooting, in case there is just some transient corruption that is causing a problem (again, if you can).

(answer was originally a series of comments)